# Return Exception Number more than 50000 using RAISERROR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

I am returning an exception from stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 as follows:

```
DECLARE @errnum nchar(5), @errmsg nvarchar(2048);
SELECT
@errnum = 51000,--RIGHT('00000' + ERROR_NUMBER(), 5),
@errmsg = @errnum + ' ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
RAISERROR (@errmsg, 16, 1);
```

The SqlException is returned in C# code with Number 50000, where is does further operations.
For some business logic reasons I need the returned number to be more than 50000.
e.g we do it using THROW keyword.

```
THROW 51000,'error',1
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a user-defined error message using sp_addmessage for this error number, then call RAISERROR using the message id:

```
RAISERROR (51000, 16, 1)
```